# Parse.com Cloud Code Google Maps API Geocoding returns ZERO_RESULTS

Tags: google-maps, http, google-maps-api-3, parse-platform, geocoding

I wrote the following parse.com cloud code function:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("googleApiLatLong", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mannheim,Opernplatz",
        success: function(httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse.text);
            response.success(httpResponse.text); // This will respond with the contents of the http response
        },
        error: function(httpResponse) {
            console.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
            response.error('Request failed with response code ' + httpResponse.status);
        }
    });
});
```

All it does for now is calling a [URL](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Mannheim) and logging the result. The URL is a request to Google's Geocoding API that returns a JSON Object when called in browser, but returns ZERO_RESULTS when called via Cloud Code.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You can try to do a `https` request with your `API key` instead, see [this doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses) for more details.

Comment: @ztan but that's not really the purpose of offering an android system API... forcing devs to use the REST API...